# Can I Toggle content of Element based on pixel height of element?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, togglebutton

Using [Bootstrap 2.3.2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/%E2%80%8E) I've previously used a toggle button to show and hide text using the [Collapse plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse) but from what I see it only allows me to reveal and hide the entire contents of an element.

What I need is to already have 170px of the element's content visible and then when the button is clicked, it reveals the rest of the text in the element - but I need to do this without adding any additional elements, it needs to be based on height.

Is this possible with Bootstrap? Or if not, jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using CSS for the element styling and then applying classes via Javascript:

The HTML:

```
<div class="toggle">
your huge text here...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.toggle{
    height:170px;
}
.open{
    height:auto;
}
```

and JS (using jQuery):

```
$('.toggle').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

What the script basically does is detect when you click on the `.toggle` and, if it is clicked, then it toggles the class `.open` which sets the propertie `height` to `auto`, leading the element with the text to be as huge as it can grow.

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/8SXNZ/1/